# Date format issue between in app and windows with c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert a string to datatime. Here is my code:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
dt = DateTime.Parse(postdate[i]);
```

It works only for dd/mm/yyyy, not work for mm/dd/yyyy because on my computer the date format is set as dd/MM/yyyy in Control Panel.

So if I want to use the application always accept valid format mm/dd/yyyy, no matter the windows date format setting is. How to implement this in c# code?

Comment: This is why we all need to be using exclusively yyyy-mm-dd...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    DateTime? dt = null;
    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(postdate[i], "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: -1: mm/dd/yyyy should be MM/dd/yyyy, and this won't work in all cultures (e.g. de-DE).  See my response.

Comment: @Joe: amended it, as indeed it should have be MM/dd/yyyy. And as you say it would be better to use the invariant culture

Comment: very interesting. if use format dd/mm/yyyy, 01/30/2009 will be converted as 01/01/2009

Comment: @KentZhou: yes the mm parses as minutes not as months. So it will more exactly have parsed as 01/01/2009 00:30:00

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateTimeValue, culture);
```

Instead of parsing with the default culture (which is based on the computer's regional settings) it will parse with the US culture which uses MM/dd/YYYY

Answer (score 1):

@JDunkerley's response is on the right track, but:

- the format specifier for a 2-digit month is MM not mm.
- using CultureInfo.CurrentCulture won't correctly parse a string containing slash separtors if you are running under a culture that uses a different separator (for example: the culture de-DE will expect a period separator.

This will work:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(postdate[i], "MM/dd/yyyy", 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```